# Reduce Array of objects to object of objects

Tags: javascript

I want to convert an Array of objects to Object of Objects.

My data:

```
var pools = [{
    dce: 3,
    lts: 2,
    name: "nift nation",
  },
  {
    dce: 1049.99,
    lts: 104.999,
    name: "NSG I.NS. Mark Select",
  },
  {
    dce: 162,
    lts: 36.157,
    name: "Shift-Team Mark Select",
  }
]
```

Desired output:

```
{
  nift_nation: {
    nift_nationDollars: "",
    nift_nationUnits: "",
    nift_nationPercentage: ""
  },
  NSG_I$NS$_Mark_Select: {
    NSG_I$NS$_Mark_SelectDollars: "",
    NSG_I$NS$_Mark_SelectUnits: "",
    NSG_I$NS$_Mark_SelectPercentage: ""
  },
  Shift__Team_Mark_Select: {
    Shift__Team_Mark_SelectDollars: "",
    Shift__Team_Mark_SelectUnits: "",
    Shift__Team_Mark_SelectPercentage: ""
  }
}
```

```js
var pools = [{
    dce: 3,
    lts: 2,
    name: "nift nation",
  },
  {
    dce: 1049.99,
    lts: 104.999,
    name: "NSG I.NS. Mark Select",
  },
  {
    dce: 162,
    lts: 36.157,
    name: "Shift-Team Mark Select",
  }
]

var suffixArray = ["Dollars", "Percentage", "Units"];

var getFieldSuffix = function(rowFieldCount) {
  switch (rowFieldCount) {
    case 0:
      return 'Dollars';
    case 1:
      return 'Units';
    case 2:
      return 'Percentage';
    default:
      return
  }
};

var replacementMap = {
  single_space: '_',
  dot: '$',
  hyphen: '__',
};

var replacer = function(str) {
  return str.replace(/[ .-]/g, l => {
    if (l == ".") return replacementMap["dot"];
    if (l == " ") return replacementMap["single_space"];
    return replacementMap["hyphen"];
  });
};

var formStructure = function dataFormatter(collection, suffixArr) {
  const data = collection.map(pool => Object.assign({
    [replacer(pool.name)]: suffixArr.reduce((acc, suffix, index) => {
      acc[replacer(pool.name) + getFieldSuffix(index % 3)] = '';
      return acc;
    }, {}),
  }));

  return Object.assign({}, ...data); //Extra step, I don't think this is the best way
}

var arrObj = formStructure(pools, suffixArray); 

console.log(arrObj)
```

I get the desired output. In `formStructure` function I store the result that is an **Array of Objects** in variable `data`, then in the next step `return Object.assign({}, ...data);`, I convert it into **Object of objects**. This approach is not optimum.

I want to be able to get **Object of objects** in variable `data` itself.

Comment: " want to be able to get Object of objects in variable data itself"... but why? A moment later the function ends and that variable is discarded. What are you hoping to achieve? I can't see how it would add any value to the code you currently have. Surely the important thing is that the `formStructure()` function returns the desired result, to be used elsewhere. It already does that. I can't see the purpose of your proposed change.

Comment: please add the wanted result as well.

Comment: @NinaScholz Edited the question and added the desired result

Comment: @ADyson If there is a lot of data, say in Millions, wouldn't that extra step hamper the performance?

Comment: It is impossible to return "*Object* of objects" using `Array.prototype.map`.

Comment: @HarshvardhanSharma I don't know. Why not try it? The best way to detect an impact on performance is to test. It's often hard to predict. There could be other parts of your code which would perform worse. Why are you worried about that step in particular? Unless you have some evidence? Of course, I'm not saying it's impossible - in fact an answer has already appeared. It just seems a bit of a random concern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use exactly the same `reduce` approach that you are already using on the `suffixArr` for your `collection`:

```
function formStructure(collection, suffixArr) {
  return collection.reduce(acc, pool) => {
    acc[replacer(pool.name)] = suffixArr.reduce((acc, suffix, index) => {
      acc[replacer(pool.name) + getFieldSuffix(index % 3)] = '';
      return acc;
    }, {});
    return acc;
  }, {});
}
```